# Differentiate PayPalConfiguration CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway

I am developing app with **PayPal** integration. While code for Paypal, `PayPalConfiguration` CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT provide different **3** option to set value for `setenvironment(..)`.

These option are as below:

```
    //1
    private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK;
    //2
    private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION;
    //3
    private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;
```

How different these **3** option while developing and integration paypal in app.

My code where I am configure Paypal.

**Code:**

```
private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK;//here set other option

  //private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "My client ID";

private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 11111;

private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
        .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
        .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
        // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
        .merchantName("Merchant Name here")
        .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
        .merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK**

Used for fake transactions only.

The SDK will not attempt to contact PayPal's servers with this option.

**ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX**

Used for development and testing.

Sandbox transactions can be seen in the dashboard.

**ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION**

Real money will be moved using this option.

Comment: in ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX  can i use real card for that??

Answer (score 1):

As per the paypal API documentation https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK#testing, both `ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK`,`ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX` used for testing the android SDK setup correctly or not. In this mode actually money won't be deducted from account. But,`ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION` is used for live payment i.e, actual payment.